# How to convert a Python Cairo matrix into Android Canvas Matrix?

Tags: android, python, matrix, transformation, cairo

Matrix in cairo graphics module in python is described as

```
cairo.Matrix(xx = 1.0, yx = 0.0, xy = 0.0, yy = 1.0, x0 = 0.0, y0 = 0.0)
```

In Andorid's Canvas, Matrix is defined as,

> The Matrix class holds a 3x3 matrix for transforming coordinates.

If those 6 affine transformation values (xx ,yx, xy, yy, x0, y0) are given, how those can be fit into 9 valued an Android's Matrix?

Comment: I don't know Android Canvas, but I assume it uses  [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Other_kinds_of_transformations) for its transformation matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

6 valued PyCairo Matrix can be mapped into 9 valued Android Matrix as followed,

```
android.graphics.Matrix() matrix = new android.graphics.Matrix();
matrix.setValues(new float[] {xx, xy, x0, yx, yy, y0, 0F, 0F, 1F});
```

In terms of Matrix mathematics, the mapping is actually looked like this,

```
| xx xy x0 |
| yx yy y0 |
| 0   0  1 |
```